# ANDROID autoCompleteView suggestions

Tags: android, search, autocomplete, autocompletetextview, threshold

I want to show suggestions not only as starting character but also a containing character... means 's' suggestions should be like `tags`,`pas`,`also`, and so on.

Comment: implement your own Filter associated with the `Adapter` or use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and implement `FilterQueryProvider`

Answer (score 1):

@sagar jagdale : 
You can use Android [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

It provides suggestions automatically when the user is typing. The list of suggestions is displayed in a drop down menu from which the user can choose an item to replace the content of the edit box with.

Check Demo [Android AutoCompleteTextView Example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example)